# Get email data with golang Facebook authentication using golang.org/x/oauth2

Tags: go, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to write a simple program using the golang.org/x/oauth2 package, and I have tried this code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672164/11094212

But, I can't get the email:
[return from facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCSfH.jpg)

This is my config:

[my config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0gDh.jpg)

Am I missed something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me**?fields=id,name,email**&access_token=

I just add **fields=id,name,email** for get the field